# File descriptor proliferation in netty 3.5.8

Tags: netty

Upon upgrading my application from netty-3.5.2 to 3.5.8, I was surprised to see file descriptor usage increase by >3X (from 275 to 874). The application uses nio socket channels pretty straightforwardly. Is there a legitimate reason for this increase, or should I be looking for a problem? The biggest increase by fd type were fifos (as reported by lsof), which went from 64 to 466. Not necessarily an issue, but I'd love to understand the change.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug.. could you please open an issue in the betty bug-tracker[1] and attach some sample code to reproduce ?

Thanks

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues?state=open